# Alternate for APImage class?

Tags: java, image

I am teaching myself Java out of a book from 2010, and it seems the classes have changed a lot since then so I can't use the current code from the book.

They use the APImage class, and I wanted to know what the current class is that has the methods:

- APImage()
- getWidth()
- getHeight()
- getPixel()
- setPixel()
- draw()
- clone()
- save()
- saveAs()

Basically, I am trying to do basic stuff with images and I can't find these methods are current methods like them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this](http://home.wlu.edu/~lambertk/hsjava/edition4/whatsnew/imagedocs/index.html?images/APImage.html).  You can download the source from [here](http://home.wlu.edu/~lambertk/hsjava/edition4/whatsnew/image.html).  Eyeballing the code, it appears to be the usual BufferedImage and friends.  (To clarify, the APImage class is not part of the Java API, but is itself using standard Java classes.)